# I'm required to manually source ~/.bashrc to display and update GIT branch in my command prompt

Tags: git, centos, command-prompt, bash

When I log into my CentOS server, my `~/.bashrc` file is being sourced.  This is evident because 1.) I have a `logger "sourcing ~/.bashrc"` message in `~/.bash_profile` and I see that message in `/var/log/messages`; and 2.) My prompt does show my current working directory, one of many things that are unique to my prompt.

However, when I cd into a Git repo, the current Git branch isn't being displayed:

```
(/home/jenkins/GitLab/testing-scripts/tests) jenkins-tests $
```

While I'm in this repo, if I source my `~/.bashrc` file, I see my Git branch as I would have anticipated:

```
(/home/jenkins/GitLab/testing-scripts/tests) jenkins-tests  $ . ~/.bashrc
(/home/jenkins/GitLab/testing-scripts/tests) jenkins-tests (devel)$
```

If I chance my branch, in order to get the current branch to be displayed, I have to `source ~/.bashrc` again.

My `~/.bashrc` executes the common `__git_ps1` command sourced from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh).

My `~/.bash_profile` contains the following:

```
GP=~/.git-prompt.sh
if [ -f $GP ]; then
  . $GP;
  logger "sourced $GP";
fi
BRC=~/.bashrc
if [ -f $BRC ]; then
  . $BRC;
  logger "sourced $BRC";
fi
BA=~/.bash_aliases
if [ -f $BA ]; then
  . $BA;
  logger "sourced $BA";
fi
```

My `~/.bashrc` is very long (colors and aliases, etc) but there are only two PS1 lines, one for root and one for not root.

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ];
then                            # You are not root
  export PS1="${BLUE}(${RED}\w${BLUE}) ${NORMAL}\h ${undgrn}$(__git_ps1) ${RED}\$ ${NORMAL}"
else
  export PS1="${RED}\u${BLUE}(${RED}\w${BLUE}) ${NORMAL}\h ${RED}\$ ${NORMAL}"
fi
```

Notice how the rest of my prompt is formatted correctly and updates when I change working directories...but Git branch does not unless I `source ~/.bashrc` again (a.k.a. every time).

From everything else I've seen, the only other thing I can think of is sourcing `/etc/bash_completion`, which I am doing very early in my `~/.bashrc` file.  The fact that the prompt displays the Git branch ought to indicate that functionally, everything is as it should be, I would think.

Stumped.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You evaluate the content of `PS1` at evaluation time of `.bashrc`. This means of course it is not updated if the branch changes or anything.

You want to set the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) instead. This is evaluated each time the prompt is shown. In there you have to evaluate the current value for `PS1` and set it. Then the display is always up to date.

Comment: Such an important detail that I have yet to embrace.  I have been experimenting with a few different things and still can't get it, though.  Could you let me know why this doesn't work:
`PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="${BLUE}(${RED}\w${BLUE}) ${NORMAL}\h ${undgrn}$(__git_ps1) ${RED}\$ ${NORMAL}"'`

Comment: The `__git_ps1` value isn't displayed in my prompt.  I tried to create a function and call it by assigning it to `PROMPT_COMMAND` and that doesn't display my git branch, either.  Right now, my prompt isn't being changed at all using the above assignment.  I am receiving the default bash prompt.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong. Do you use bash at all? If I execute your version from the comment, my prompt changes to what you coded, and on each new prompt showing it complains about `__git_ps1` not being found.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in bash.  The PROMPT_COMMAND doesn't seem to do anything for me at all.  I can play with PS1 on its own and source the file (`~/.bashrc`) and see my prompt change but a simple `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n Hi!'` never seems to get executed.  Logging out and back in, sourcing...I don't seem to be getting anything from it.  I've am now doing `PROMPT_COMMAND='gps=$(__git_ps1)'` then crafting my PS1 with the ${gps} variable.  It seems very straight-forward but I don't see evidence that PROMPT_COMMAND is executing.

Comment: Finally got it.  First, I had another line further down in my `~/.bashrc` that was checking if `$TERM` was `xterm*`.  That was resetting my `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  Then, I built PS1 inside the function I was calling with `PROMPT_COMMAND` and it finally worked!  Thanks for letting me know about `PROMPT_COMMAND`